# How to locate iphone simulator with different versions of xcode like 4/5/6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have different versions of xcode installed in different directory under Application folder. When I browse Library folder from MAC HD/user/library/...... its takes me to default version "iphone simulator/applications. But I want ot locate simulator for other xcode version.
How can I go to that path?

Answer (score 0):

These paths are different for each version of Xcode. The path for Xcode 6 for example starts at ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator. For a really useful read regarding this matter, please refer to this link (and the other two links at the beginning of that article): http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-6-store-apps-documents.html

You should also check other questions here regarding this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcode+simulator+location